# ios UITableView Crash with Custom Container View Controller

Tags: ios

In my storyboard I have 2 views one master and one detail with list. I want to show detail view on master. When I add detail to master like that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:detailVC];
    [self.view addSubview:detailVC.view];
}
```

I get crash like that:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Im sure that there is everything ok with my table viewController becouse when I set it to rootViewController there is everything ok. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is an error with your tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath. Give us the code for that method and we can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its an issue with tableview delegate methods. In story board please use static cell for your table view controller and remove table view delegate methods or else implement all required table view delegate methods.